# Expo.ImagePicker works within Expo, but not in Standalone Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Our app allows the user take pictures (and select pictures) from it.

I've used the **Expo** component **ImagePicker** for that, as it provides a simple API.

And it works perfectly inside expo (both `exp start` and `exp publish`), but it does not work within a standalone apk.

When I try to invoke `ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync()`, I catch an **EUNSPECIFIED** exception, but that *only* in the standalone apk.

**Details**

An excerpt of the code:

```
import { ImagePicker } from 'expo';

(...)
const image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [3, 5],
});

(...)
let image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [3, 5],
});
```

It works well within expo, including `exp publish` version.

As for my permissions in the `app.json`, what I have is the following:

```
(...)
"android": {
  "package": "br.com.miredefamilia",
  "versionCode": 3, 
  "permissions": [
    "android.permissions.CAMERA",
    "android.permissions.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "android.permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
  ]
}
```

I have also tried without the `android.permissions`.

The mobile does request for the permission, I accept it, and it does not launch the camera / picker, like it does within the `expo`.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following changes have fixed the problem:

In the `app.json`

```
"android": {
  "package": "br.com.miredefamilia",
  "versionCode": 3, 
  "permissions": [
    "CAMERA",
    "READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
  ]
}
```

And the calls to the component, I removed the parameters:

`const image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();`

`let image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();`

I also removed the dependency:

`"react-native-camera": "^0.10.0",`

I don't know exactly which one solved the problem, but one of them did.

Answer (score 3):

This is the proper solution with docs link

Ask for `Permission.CAMERA` and `Permission.CAMERA_ROLL`

```
const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA, Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
if (status === 'granted') {
   ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: 'Images',
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [1, 1]
    })
} else {
   // ask user to turn on permission here
}
```

Also update the app.json with this permissions

`CAMERA`
`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
`READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE`

[Docs link here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickerlaunchcameraasyncoptions)

[Reference](https://forums.expo.io/t/imagepicker-launchcameraasync-does-not-work/15316/3)